# Wipe iphone, switch carriers, get new carrier-locked iphone, restore?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

Let's say I have an AT&T iphone 5. I regularly back it up with itunes.
I decide to switch carriers to Verizon. I wipe my iphone, sell it, and get a brand new Verizon iphone 5.

Can I simply plug that iphone into itunes, do a restore from backup, and have everything exactly as it was before? Or is there enough of a difference between the carrier-locked phones that this would not smoothly restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will be able to** restore the backup, especially if your old device wasn't jailbroken (if it is, some space might end up wasted due to the unofficial apps' preferences & files).

Even if you look to already expect this, remember the unlock won't carry over.

Comment: No jailbreak, no unlock. Just a stock iphone running stock iOS. Thanks.